# Create extra "special" mailbox in Mail.app

Tags: apple-mail, mailbox

Anyone knows if i can add an extra mailbox under "Mailboxes" in Mail.app (or if a plugin exists to do this)?

not a Smart mailbox, no mailbox under "on my mac" but just another icon under "mailboxes" as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Not what you're asking, but if all else fails: using IMAP you can have folders on the server. Those folders are shown as a child of an account's Inbox. Not visible when Inbox is collapsed, like in your screen capture, but shown when Inbox and the account within that is expanded. (And, using small icons shortens the drag-and-drop distance a lot.)

Comment: btw, your email addresses are in the screenshot for public view.

Comment: Like I commented on Kio's answer, to enhance my earlier comment on the IMAP workaround a bit: for some setups, you have to prefix new folder names with `INBOX/` (more precisely: with the value for "IMAP Path Prefix" from the account's advanced preferences).

Comment: And certainly not what you're asking, but you can open multiple Mail windows (menu File » New Viewer Window) which might make occasional re-organizing a bit easier. Also, there's menu Message » Move to [..] Again. And finally: what about a Smart Mailbox that holds all flagged messages, and then flag messages? Or one for messages that have To Do's? You could then drag the "Smart Mailboxes" placeholder to sit *above* your Inbox. Closest I can get...

Answer (score 1):

You can create mailboxes (aka "folders") on an existing IMAP or Exchange account by selecting from the menu **Mailbox** > **New Mailbox...** and select the account and parent folder you wish from the drop down menu.

If you want sub folders of your Inbox, you have to configure those outside of Mail.  Mail will display sub folders of the Inbox of a given account, however it will not help you create one.

At my office, I have a PC that I have to use for one specific application.  Luckily, that gives me the opportunity to configure my server-side rules and folders the way I want them.  If you don't have a Windows OS to boot up to do a quick fix to your account, you may ask your IT department how you can use the Outlook Web Access portal.  Some companies just have a "check email" link on their home page.

The same goes for your IMAP account.  I'm not sure what you use, so I can't give you detailed instructions.  Google doesn't seem to like subfolders in general, so I can tell you that's a lost cause in Gmail.

If for some reason you DO have a sub folder of any other folder that's not showing up, then you need to select a folder from the offending account and select from the menu **Mailbox** > **Rebuild**.  This can also fix an issue where certain emails may not appear.

Comment: *Mail will display sub folders of the Inbox of a given account, however it will not help you create one.* -- for some setups, you have to prefix new folder names with `INBOX/` (more precisely: with the value for "IMAP Path Prefix" from the account's advanced preferences).

Comment: I'm afraid that subfolders under inbox is not what i'm looking for but i'm looking to put a new folder under "mailboxes" in between 'inbox' and 'sent' ... I think that's generally just not possible ...

Comment: Ah...  yup, that's right.  All created folders show up below under your account's name.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP access is really what your trying to describe, as far as I can tell.

The folders on your mac are listed their because they are literally only existing on your macintosh...  I assume your Popping your email?

If so, check with your provider to see if they offer imap support.  With imap, your mail is actually stored on the server, and thus you can have "mailboxes" / folders on the server...

Comment: I've got 2 accounts defined, one being on an Exchange box and one being a Gmail account pulled in through IMAP, so if i unfold my inbox by clicking the arrow my 2 IMAP mailboxes are show.
What i want to accomplish is that i have one local folder called 'Defer' under mailboxes, not specifically linked to one of my two imap accounts.

Comment: With this setup, you should just be able to drag and drop the local folder to inbox that you want it to be contained under...  If not, then create a new mailbox, specifying it to be stored under the inbox you want it associated with.  Then drag and drop the emails to the new mailbox.